# hiding the hash in sms for smsRetreiver Android

Tags: android, sms-retriever-api

I am using [Secure Android OTP & Account Verification using the SMS Retriever API](https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/autofill-otp-verification-with-latest-sms-retriever-api-73c788636783), In oreder for the service to work My incoming sms should be in the foloowing format:

```
<#> Your code is: 401947
FA+9qCX9VSu
```

With the <#> At the begging and the hash in the end, is there a wy to remove this (or at least make it invisible for the user?

Thanks!

Comment: without this auto read will not worked

Comment: No you can't edit your message.But one thing you can do is  you can use broadcast receiver to listen incoming message. and then you can extract digit from string.... thank you

Comment: @MachhindraNeupane that requires the READ_SMS permission which but you can no longer upload apps to the play store that requires such permission

Comment: Yes you need to take run time permission from user

Answer (score 0):

No, I think the SDK reads that character to determine if it should continue reading the rest of the text that is why it is required according to the documentation.